# Valgrind error -Address is zero bytes after allocation - C/C++

Tags: c++, arrays, valgrind

I am valgrinding my project for a memory leak. I am getting an error for which I cant understand the root cause of it. My code is huge so I will put chunks here that are needed.

Basically I have an array in a function called `find_pulses` that I dynamically allocate like this:

```
float*rmsArray;
    rmsArray = (float*)malloc((N-pulse_samplewidth+1)*sizeof(float));
```

I debugged to this point and found that `N-pulse_samplewidth+1` is non zero. (its actually **~ 2^21**)

I populate the values to this array like this:

```
for (int loop1 = 0; loop1 < N-pulse_samplewidth; ++loop1) {
// populate rms array here.
}
```

I send this array to another function called `findpeak` like this:

```
 int* ans = findpeak(rmsArray,N,pulse_samplewidth,startsec,min,max,x);
```

declaration of `findpeak` goes like this:

```
int* findpeak(float* data, int n, int pulse_samplewidth,float startsec,float min,float max, float* x);
```

inside the `findpeak` function, I add a particular value from `data` to a stack like this:

```
std::stack<float> peaks_y;
for (int loop1 = 0; loop1 < n; ++loop1) {
if( some condition)
{
peaks_y.push(data[loop1]); // point of error.
}
}
```

The place where I push it on stack, I get the following error on valgrind

```
==17917== Invalid read of size 4
==17917==    at 0x4109C2: findpeak(float*, int, int, float, float, float, float*) (stat_utility.C:358)
==17917==    by 0x410778: find_pulses(int, float*, int, int, float) (stat_utility.C:321)
==17917==    by 0x410F46: find_pulses(int, floatcomplex *, int, int, float) (stat_utility.C:426)
==17917==    by 0x403385: main (DetectRFI.C:207)
==17917==  Address 0x18796c20 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8,326,112 alloc'd
==17917==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17917==    by 0x410507: find_pulses(int, float*, int, int, float) (stat_utility.C:285)
==17917==    by 0x410F46: find_pulses(int, floatcomplex *, int, int, float) (stat_utility.C:426)
==17917==    by 0x403385: main (DetectRFI.C:207)
```

I debugged to this point and I found I had all the values populated on the array as necessary. Can anyone tell me what the error actually means??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're reading beyond the end of `rmsArray`.

That's because you treat `N` as the array size, when the actual size is`N-pulse_samplewidth+1`, which is less than `N` assuming `pulse_samplewidth` is greater than 1.

Comment: yes I was. why didn't I notice this earlier when it is so daringly visible ? anyway thanks a lot.